# Regular expression to filter urls with strings repeated 3 times or more

Tags: regex, regular-language

I am using the regular expression `(\b\w+\b)\W+\1{3,}` to filter urls with strings repeated three times or more. I tried `(\b\w+\b)\W+\1{3,}` or `(\b\w+\b)\W{3,}+\1` but of no help

http://rubular.com/r/6IyCPyBiuW -> `(\b\w+\b)\W+\1` -> this works to find words repeated more than one time only but I am interested to find words repeated more than three times.

http://rubular.com/r/O9NcobUsTX -> `(\b\w+\b)\W+\1{3,}` -> this doesn't work to find words repeated three or more

Comment: There was a flaw with the answer previously. Updated with an alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. It would be great if you give a brief explanation on how you came up with that expression. I am a beginner in using regex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following regular expression works:

```
(\w+\W)\1{2,}
```

The above matches the non-word character as well, **exactly**, So, alternately, you could use the rather ugly looking

```
(\w+)(?:\W+\1){2,}
```

**Details:**

```
\w    -> single word character
\w+   -> one or more word characters
\W    -> non-word character
\1    -> back-reference to capturing group #1 (in this case, (\w+)
{2,}  -> 2 or more of (?:\W+\1)
(?:)  -> grouping without actually capturing anything
```

http://rubular.com/r/Trb41xxCAt

Comment: Thank you so much!! It helped me fix my problem. However, I want to understand the usage of '\1' over '+\1'

Comment: @user1830069 `\1` is a back-reference, which refers to the string captured by the first capturing group `(...)`. The `+` goes with the quantifier before it, and says one or more of that. For example, `\w+` means 1 or more word characters. It is not to be read `+\1`.

Comment: Is it possible to modify the first expression to work also when the last repeated word is in the end of the line? It doesn't work when there is a new line after the last word. It works with grep, but it doesn't work e.g. here https://regexr.com/3ipck